# JMeter https.keyStoreStartIndex not working

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, keystore

I have an application that requires client side certificates. My users.jks has multiple certs in it, test_user_1 - test_user_50. The cert works and I am able to successfully use any of the users in it when I try it manually through firefox so I know that part is ok.

I have added these lines to the system.properties file:

javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\path_to_cert\users.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=cert_password

https.keyStoreStartIndex=3
https.keyStoreEndIndex=10

I originally had it in the user.properties file but it was not applying so I moved it to the system.properties file instead.

Everytime I run the test, no matter what index I set, it always selects test_user_1 for ALL of the threads.

Is there some other place I need to make another settings change or did I do something obviously wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter Properties reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#ssl_config):

> SSL (Java) System properties are now in system.properties
> JMeter no longer converts javax.xxx property entries in jmeter.properties into System properties. These must now be defined in the system.properties file or on the command-line. The system.properties file gives more flexibility.

so the correct location is *system.properties*

If you want each user to use different entry from the keystore:

1. List all certificate aliases in a CSV file
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the entries from the CSV file from step 1 into a JMeter Variable
3. Add [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) and use the variable from step 2 as the certificate alias

More information: [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites)